# Possible to remove from the kendo ui view not from the datasource?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We have a soft delete functionality in kendo UI grid. When on click of delete, it should mark a flag to true and immediately remove the item from the kendo view. I have tried grid.dataSource.view().remove(selectedItem). But is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `databound` event add:

```
dataBound: function (e) {
                //get all rows
                var rows = e.sender.tbody.children();

                for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
                    var row = $(rows[j]);
                    var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(row);

                    //check your delete property here
                    if (dataItem && dataItem.hidden) {
                        row.addClass("hiddden");
                    }else{
                        row.removeClass("hiddden");
                    }
         }
}
```

In CSS:

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you need correctly working pagination on your grid than add on initialization:

```
    var ds = grid.sender.dataSource;
    //get dataSource's array of filters
    var curr_filters = ds.filter().filters;
    //create new filter object for hidden prop
    var new_filter = { field: "hidden", operator: "eq", value: true };
    //add new_filter to filters
    curr_filters.push(new_filter);
    //apply the filters
    ds.filter(curr_filters)
```

That way you dont need class modifications.

Comment: Thanks for your respnse,  This snippet of code will hide the row from the grid. But still kendo pager will remain intact. Since the datasource is still holding the record, the pager shows the count inclusive of the record hidden. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Or better you should add that filter on datasource intialization

Comment: Exactly this is what I looking for. Thanks Buddy.

Comment: Instead have added the filter while constructing the datasource itself.

Comment: Mark as answer if it was helpful that will prevent other people to post new answers in future